Adjust the width of a table in a tcolorbox
I would like columns of different widths to be able to fit the width of my tcolorbox. As you can see in my example, I tried to create 3 columns of different size (0.2, 0.2 and 0.6) but it exceeds the tcolorbox...
Thank you in advance for your help.
MWE :
\documentclass{article}
% Allow the usage of UTF-8 characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor} 

\newtcolorbox{tcbtable}[2][]{
bottom=0pt,
bottomtitle=4pt,
boxsep=0pt,
center title, 
enhanced jigsaw,
colbacktitle=red, 
colframe=red,
coltitle=white,
float=h!t,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,
left=0pt,
opacityback=0,
right=0pt,
sharp corners,
top=0pt,
title={#2},
toptitle=4pt,
#1
}

% Start the document
\begin{document}

% Create a new 1st level heading
\section{Main Heading}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcbtable}
{Box-1}%
\rowcolors{1}{}{red!20}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}% 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value-1} & Value-2 \\
Value-3 & Value-4  & Value-5 \\
Value-6 & Value-7 & Value-8 \\
Value-9 & Value-10 & Value-11
\end{tabularx}%
\end{tcbtable}

\end{document}




In your document, the tabularx environment doesn't use a single X-type column. How is tabularx supposed to do its work?
I'd like to suggest a different setup: Since you require the relative (usable) column widths to obey the ratio 1:1:3, and since we can assign the X column type to all three columns, it follows that we need to specify relative widths of 0.6, 0.6, and 1.8, as 0.6+0.6+1.8=3=# of X-type columns.

\documentclass{article}
% Allow the usage of UTF-8 characters
%% That’s the default nowadays 
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor} 

\newtcolorbox{tcbtable}[2][]{
bottom=0pt,
bottomtitle=4pt,
boxsep=0pt,
center title, 
enhanced jigsaw,
colbacktitle=red, 
colframe=red,
coltitle=white,
float=h!t,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,
left=0pt,
opacityback=0,
right=0pt,
sharp corners,
top=0pt,
title={#2},
toptitle=4pt,
#1
}

% new:
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

% Start the document
\begin{document}

% Create a new 1st level heading
\section{Main Heading}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{tcbtable}{Box-1}%
\rowcolors{1}{}{red!20}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt} % default: 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\arrayrulecolor{red} % <-- new
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ C{0.6}|C{0.6}|C{1.8} } % 0.6+0.6+1.8 = 3
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value-1} & Value-2 \\
Value-3 & Value-4  & Value-5  \\
Value-6 & Value-7  & Value-8  \\
Value-9 & Value-10 & Value-11
\end{tabularx}
\end{tcbtable}

\end{document}

